# sosl query wildcard not returning correct results

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a function that uses a sosl query:

```
private List<Product2> runSoslToExecute() { 
    List<List<Product2>> searchResults = [FIND :query IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Product2 (Id, Name)];
    List<Product2> results = new List<Product2>();
    for(Product2 p : searchResults[0]) {
        results.add(p);
    }
    return results;
}
```

If I search for "AB*" then I also get results that include "1AB...".  I thought the "*" wildcard only searches in the middle and end of the search and not at the beginning?  Is there a way to run the sosl search so it only searches "AB" at the beginning?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `like`, for example,

```
Select Id, Name from Account where Name like 'AB%'
```